# Load category menu dynamically or with asynchronous request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, nopcommerce

I was working on nopcommerce 2.40.

In my database I have 100s of different categories (Xml is created using these categories), which are loaded using Telerik menu.

With this method It takes too much time to load categories, and my website's html also looks distorted for short span due to this (This menu is being created using xml which is having tree view structure of categories. This xml is also cached).

Is there any other way to load my categories dynamically or using ajax request so that loading of my website category menu becomed fast.
.
I have also implemented Angular Js for category page loading. Workaround with angular js can also be used.

```
<div class="menudiv">
            @{
          Html.Telerik().Menu().Name("sitemap")
          .BindTo("sitemap", (item, Menus) =>
          {
              var imageUrl = ((Telerik.Web.Mvc.SiteMapNode)Menus).Attributes["ImageUrl"];
              if (imageUrl != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl.ToString()))
              {
                  item.ImageUrl = imageUrl.ToString();
                  //item.SpriteCssClasses.
              }
          })
          .Items(x =>
          {

              if (adminMenuPlugins.Count() > 0)
              {

                  x.Add().Text(T("Admin.Plugins").ToHtmlString()).Items(y =>
                  {
                      foreach (var adminMenuPlugin in adminMenuPlugins)
                      {
                          adminMenuPlugin.BuildMenuItem(y.Add());

                      }
                  });

              }
          })
          .OpenOnClick(false)

          .Render();
            }
        </div>
```